# Dell Studio MT Beep Codes

Tags: motherboard

My Google kung fu has failed me and I cannot find what I know I've found in the past: Dell Studio MT beep codes.  I've got a black screen, no post, and two beeps pause two beeps pause two beeps....  First, any chance anyone can point me to a link of the common Dell beep codes that would be cool.  Second, any thoughts on what might be busted based on two beeps?  Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this page and type the service code for the machine (it's on a tag on the Machine somewhere). If it's a laptop it's on the bottom of the machine.

http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19?c=us&l=en&s=dhs

Once you have the tag you can download the specific manual for your machine (that's where the beep codes will be listed).

Two beeps is usually a bad memory problem meaning the memory doesn't post. You can open the door on the machine and pull the memory out and put it back in to see if that solves the problem. (Make sure all power is removed from the machine and that you're grounded.)

Comment: Thanks, I've looked through the service manual and don't see a reference to beep codes.  It's got lots of good info on how to swap out parts though.  I'll take another look to make sure my eyes aren't missing something.

Comment: I don't see beep codes on the doc but a reseat of the ram seems to have stabilized the machine.  Many thanks for your help.